# Velocity if condition insertion into xdocreport docx template

Tags: velocity, xdocreport

Reviewed XDocReport wiki for conditional text.

https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMainCondition

Not clear on how to embed velocity template code into docx mergefield.

In docx, a mergefield of **watershare** has been created.

The context replace code is as follows:

```
IContext context = report.createContext();

// populate map
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("water_share", "#if( $water_share_transfer_flag )\n"
  + "\t<strong>Velocity!</strong>\n"
  + "#end");
map.put("water_share_transfer_flag", new Boolean("true"));
context.putMap(map);
```

the resulting docx replaces the **water_share** mergefield with the velocity condition, but doesnt replace variable water_share_transfer_flag and display result **Velocity!!**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your docx as Velocity template and IContext to VelocityContext. So if you wish to use #if to manage condition you must not use it in your context like you have done, but use it inside mergefields (inside your docx) :

- create a mergefield which contains your start condition with #if. In your case the mergefield contains:

`#if( $water_share_transfer_flag )`

- add the content which must be displayed in your docx after this mergefield. In your case:

`Velocity!`

- create a second mergefield after the content "Velocity!", which contains your end condition of #end:

`#end`

Comment: are you suggesting to insert mergefield in docx as follows -  { MERGEFIELD "#if ( {MERGEFIELD $water_share_transfer_flag } ) Paragraph text goes here #end" }.

Comment: Also saw Issue 91, which appears to solve similar issue - https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/detail?id=91

Comment: Figured it out, value should be { MERGEFIELD "if($condition_flag_as_boolean)"} Paragraph text goes here { MERGEFIELD #end}. Thanks for your assistance Angelo

Comment: I detailled my answer. Don't miss the # for your start if (it's #if($condition_flag_as_boolean) and not if($condition_flag_as_boolean))